# Woocommerce product title depends of gravity form id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to make a condition for product titles depends of gravity form ID. There is several forms for each product type. And I can't find any solutions for this.
For example, I imagine  something like this: if gravity form id  = 2 echo 'buy', if gravity form id = 1 echo 'buy with my features'.
Maybe there is possible with post meta conditions, but I don't know which one is actual for gravity forms.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript will be able to do this if it is just for display

if you want to do this on the php level you need to give more info on how are you calling your gravity forms.

```
<script>
if( $('#gravityform_ID_Name_goes_here_3').length )){
$('h1.page_title_class_name').html() // do your change here.
}

</script>
```

If you are selecting which gravity form to display based on the built-in woocommerce product add-on extension then each product should have a meta key for the gravity form ID they are displaying.

With this info you can put some case statements on your `get_the_title();`
sudo code below.

```
<?php 
$your_form_id = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'gravityform-id', true);
$your_title = get_the_title();
switch($your_form_id){
    case 1
    //code here
    break;
    case 2 ect...
    break
    default
    //no match code here
}
echo '<h1>' . $your_title . '</h1>';
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, and you are right, I looking for php solution. My forms calling non-latin-characters names, so let it be form1, form2, form3 (actually it will be more than 10 forms).

Comment: And for products I've choose one of this. And "pre-title" word should be different, for example, if there is a dress for custom sewing with individual sizes and I choose Form1 to make avaliable sizing fields, there should be "Order tailoring",but if there is fabric piece, there should be "Buy enough meters"

Comment: @MariaPuchkova what I mean was where does your gform display logic happen ( example: is it at the beginning of your product loop with some case statement? or just some setting/plugin extension ) should always post what code you have done so far when asking questions.

Comment: I just install the plugin and addon for woocommerce and it automatically works, there is no special steps from me to display forms at single product template. There is a title for each form that may be helps, but unfortunaly it displayed after variable attributes, which is looks as thumbnails (types of fabric).

Comment: There isn't a "install and just works" solution from gravity form. If you are selecting which gravity form to display on each and every product (that is the out of box woo-commerce solution) see update on possible approach.